# Unity WWW time out error on iOS 9.1

Tags: unity-game-engine

I use **WWW** (not WWWForm) to upload an image file to server.
It's ok when I run on iOS 9 or below, but when I test on iOS 9.1, **WWW** return a "time out" error.
Anyone know about this error :((

```
string server_ip = url;
byte[] file_byte_array = array_of_file;
var post_header = new Dictionary<string, string>();
WWW stream = new WWW(server_ip, file_byte_array, post_header);

yield return www;

if(www.error != null)
{
   Debug.LogError("ERROR : " + www.error);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please have a read of [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)! Tell us what you have tried, and provide all necessary details.

Comment: Is it over HTTP? Have you disabled Application Transport Security checks?

Comment: @peterept yeah it's over HTTP, but when I **download** an image, it's OK.  Error is returned when I **upload**  an image :((

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I can't use WWW to upload, so I've tried C# Socket

```
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentType = "text/plain";

            byte[] fileToSend = arrByteAva;
            request.ContentLength = fileToSend.Length;

            using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                // Send the file as body request.
                requestStream.Write(fileToSend, 0, fileToSend.Length);
                requestStream.Close();
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because of the AppTransport security on xcode 7. Adding this on your info.plist : NSAppTransportSecurity with type Dictionary and inside this add NSAllowArbitraryLoads with boolean type and set it to YES